# How to save JSON Nested value using PHP as txt.file or Mysql database

Tags: php, json

I have a nested JSON object and i want to save the values into a txt file.
This is the nested Json object

```
"objectJSON":{
     "alt":"136.22",
     "lat":"46.7484",
     "lng":"33.0685"
}
```

I use the following PHP code to save the values into a txt.file

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");

$obj = json_decode($json);
$decoded = base64_decode(json_encode($obj->data));
$encoded = json_encode($obj->objectJSON);


$fp = @fopen("TMP.txt", "a");  //Open and write into TMP.txt
        fwrite($fp, $encoded);
        fwrite($fp,"\r\n");
        fclose($fp);

?>
```

And here are the values into the TMP.txt file

```
"{\"alt\":136.22,\"lat\":46.7484,\"lng\":33.0685}"
```

And here is the problem:

What do I have to change/add to save only the "alt" value in the TMP.txt file?

HERE ARE MORE INFORMATION ABOUT MY PROJECT.

I receive the data via a lora node to a lora gateway which send them to my lora server. Here is a part from the lora node code that has been uploaded on it:

```
void GPSWrite()
{
  /*Convert GPS data to format*/
  datastring1 +=dtostrf(flat, 0, 6, gps_lat);   
  datastring2 +=dtostrf(flon, 0, 6, gps_lon);
  //datastring3 +=dtostrf(falt, 0, 2, gps_alt);
  
  if(flon!=1000.000000)
  {  
  strcat(gps_lon,",");
  strcat(gps_lon,gps_lat); 
  //strcat(gps_lon,","); 
  //strcat(gps_lon,gps_alt);
    int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
      //datasend.toFloat();
      atof(gps_lon);
     //Serial.println((char*)datasend);
    Serial.println("Testing converted data:");
    Serial.println(gps_lon);
    // atof(gps_alt);
    // Serial.print(gps_alt);
  }
  
  strcpy(datasend,gps_lon); //the format of datasend is longtitude,latitude,altitude
  Serial.print("###########    ");
  Serial.print("NO.");
  Serial.print(count);
  Serial.println("    ###########");
  Serial.println("The longtitude and latitude are:");
  Serial.print("[");
  Serial.print((char*)datasend);
  Serial.print("]");
  Serial.print("");
  /*
  for(int k = 0; k < 20;k++)
  {
  Serial.print("[");
  Serial.print(datasend[k], HEX);
  Serial.print("]");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("");*/
  count++;
  }
  
  int32_t lat = flat * 10000;
  int32_t lng = flon * 10000;

  datasend[0] = lng;
  datasend[1] = lng >> 8;
  datasend[2] = lng >> 16;

  datasend[3] = lat;
  datasend[4] = lat >> 8;
  datasend[5] = lat >> 16;
  smartdelay(1000);
}

static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do 
  {
    while (ss.available())
    {
      gps.encode(ss.read());
    }
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}
void loop() {
    os_runloop_once();
     }
```

The application server decodes the data with the following function:

```
function Decode(fPort, bytes) {
  var decoded = {};
  var hexString=bin2HexStr(bytes);
  return rakSensorDataDecode(hexString);
}

// convert array of bytes to hex string.
// e.g: 0188053797109D5900DC140802017A0768580673256D0267011D040214AF0371FFFFFFDDFC2E
function bin2HexStr(bytesArr) {
  var str = "";
  for(var i=0; i<bytesArr.length; i++) {
    var tmp = (bytesArr[i] & 0xff).toString(16);
    if(tmp.length == 1) {
      tmp = "0" + tmp;
    }
    str += tmp;
  }
  return str;
}

// convert string to short integer
function parseShort(str, base) {
  var n = parseInt(str, base);
  return (n << 16) >> 16;
}

// convert string to triple bytes integer
function parseTriple(str, base) {
  var n = parseInt(str, base);
  return (n << 8) >> 8;
}

// decode Hex sensor string data to object
function rakSensorDataDecode(hexStr) {
  var str = hexStr;
  var myObj = {};

  while (str.length > 4) {
    var flag = parseInt(str.substring(0, 4), 16);
    {
      
     
        myObj.lat = (bytes[3] | bytes[4]<<8 | bytes[5]<<16 | (bytes[5] & 0x80 ? 0xFF<<24 : 0)) / 10000;
        myObj.lng = (bytes[0] | bytes[1]<<8 | bytes[2]<<16 | (bytes[2] & 0x80 ? 0xFF<<24 : 0)) / 10000;
        myObj.alt = ((bytes[6] << 8) + bytes[7])/100;
        str = str.substring(22); 
    
    }
  }

  return myObj;
}
```

so I get through my application server the following results:
[received data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcH3j.jpg)

Then I use the php script to save data on txt, file. As I have told you, the problem is that I can save all data but can't save for example only the altitude.

Comment: so you want to save in the file `"{\"alt\":136.22}"` or only `136.22`

Comment: I would like to save only 136.22

Comment: ok posted the answer

Comment: this `$encoded->alt` will give you alt value

Comment: remove all the encode/decode base64 decode confusion and simply use `$obj->objectJSON->alt` you don't re-encode it if you want the string from the object

Comment: $encoded->alt returns an empty line

Comment: $obj->objectJSON->alt also returns an empty line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can save my data in a txt file and I can insert my data into a MySQL database at the same time. Thank you all for your help. Here is the PHP script

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($json);
$decoded = base64_decode(json_encode($obj->data));

$fp = @fopen("TMP.txt", "a");   //Open and write into TMP.txt
      fwrite($fp,$decoded);
      fwrite($fp,"\r\n");
      fclose($fp);

$server         = "#######";
$username       = "#######";
$password       = "#######";
$DB             = "#######";

$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $DB);
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$insert = "INSERT INTO gpssensor(longitude, latitude) VALUES ($decoded)";
$conn->query($insert);
$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to extract the value from the `object`:

```
$fp = @fopen("TMP.txt", "a");  //Open and write into TMP.txt
fwrite($fp, $decoded->alt);
//                  ^^^^^^^
fwrite($fp,"\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: it returns an empty line

Comment: @BillCheimaras try now

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I will try again on Monday because I can not have access on the pc this weekend

Comment: Finally I have access to my pc via vnc viewer. ``` $fp = @fopen("TMP.txt", "a");  //Open and write into TMP.txt
fwrite($fp, $decoded->alt);
//                  ^^^^^^^
fwrite($fp,"\r\n");
fclose($fp); ``` returns an empty line

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is decode and then encode and write the proper one:

```
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj  = json_decode($json);
file_put_contents("TMP.txt", json_encode($obj->objectJSON->alt));
```

If you want to append then:

```
file_put_contents("TMP.txt",
                  file_get_contents("TMP.txt") . json_encode($obj->objectJSON->alt));
```

But that won't be valid JSON in the file.

Comment: "*it did not work*" is very unhelpful. Don't let people guess about the error or problem you are having, describe it.

Comment: I am sorry, it gives back an empty line

Comment: file_put_contents("TMP.txt", json_encode($obj->objectJSON->alt)); returns"null"

Comment: file_put_contents("TMP.txt", file_get_contents("TMP.txt") . json_encode($obj->objectJSON->alt)); also returns "null"

Answer (score 1):

You are using the encoded data, instead use decoded data if you want to access the 'alt' attribute, here is an example :

```
<?php

$obj = (object) [
  "objectJSON" => [
    'alt' => '136.22',
    'lat' => '46.7484',
    'lng' => '33.0685'
  ]
];

$encoded = json_encode($obj->objectJSON);
$decoded = json_decode($encoded); 


$fp = @fopen("TMP.txt", "a");  //Open and write into TMP.txt
        fwrite($fp, $decoded->alt);
        fwrite($fp,"\r\n");
        fclose($fp);


?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have edit my question by giving more information about the project